# How to Customize BackPressed event in Windows Application Development for every page to return to a home page

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

How to customize BackPressed event so that every page when BackPressed returns a specified 'Home' Page. Stack is not required to be maintained.

```
        public App()
        {
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
        }

        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {

            Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (frame == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (frame.CanGoBack && !e.Handled)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                frame.GoBack();
            }
     }
```

Comment: You need to override the backpressed method and it needs to be protected @SonarGönül

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann It worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the backpressed method and it needs to be protected.